# Is it correct "It's gone stress already..."

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct to say the following:

> This is gone stress already...

In a scenario in which I have got rid of my stress and I no longer worry about the thing that had caused it.

Answer (score 1):

Although that might seem to make sense, It would be more natural to rephrase it slightly:

> The stress is already gone.

Or:

> The stress is gone already.

Answer (score 1):

No. Whether with *it* or *this*, they are not idiomatic, and will probably not be understood. There is no obvious grammatical role for *stress* in those forms - certainly it cannot be the subject.